# skipLocationChange: true is not working ; shows URL

Tags: angular, angular7-router

I am very new to angular and don't know how to ask this question.
I am facing an issue when I redirect to another component using router, `skipLocationChange: true` still shows current (called) component URL in browser,

syntax for router is as below

```
this.myRouter.navigate(['test-component2',{skipLocationChange:true}])
```

and it return  `http://localhost:4200/test-component2;skipLocationChange=true` in the browser.
Issue is also reported as bug [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29871).
Is there any alternative to it or any solution of current issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a syntax mistake to me. Try:

```
this.myRouter.navigate(['test-component2'],{skipLocationChange:true});
```

Comment: great was my mistake